# How to add support for concurrency to a VM

Tags: concurrency, virtual-machine, programming-languages

I implemented my own functional (not OO) programming language and a VM reading Crafting Interpreters, and I wanted to know how to implement concurrency.

I searched for resources on this, but I still have no idea how to implement a concurrent VM.

I'm most interested in Erlang-like Actor Model and hope to integrate one into the language.